# How to create using XML::TreeBuilder element with CDATA?

Tags: xml, perl

I use XML::TreeBuilder for creating and parsing of xml files.
Is it possible to create element with CDATA using XML::TreeBuilder?

```
<script>
<![CDATA[
function matchwo(a,b)
{
if (a < b && a < 0) then
  {
  return 1;
  }
else
  {
  return 0;
  }
}
]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

XML::TreeBuilder uses [XML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aParser) to read and parse XML and creates a bunch of XML::Elements.  If you want to then manipulate the XML by creating new tags and so on, you probably want to use [XML::DOM](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aDOM) or [XML::Generator](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aGenerator).